# What do two keys in FB Messenger Secret Chat mean?

Tags: encryption, facebook

Okay, this is a real situation but I will use the classic names.

Alice and Bob are chatting via FB Messenger Secret Chats.

When Bob taps on settings, "Your keys" shows "BB BB BB", and "Alice's keys" shows "AA 11 AA" and "AA 22 AA".

When Alice taps on settings, "Your keys" shows "AA 11 AA" and "AA 22 AA", and "Bob's keys" shows "BB BB BB".

Question: why does Alice have two keys? Alice is only using a single device. Has Alice been compromised somehow? Is it possible to delete that unwanted key? Everything I can find on FB docs showcases a single key per side scenario.

Comment: If you wish to learn more about encrypted message communication,  please do spend some time to study PKC.  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

Comment: I think you entirely misunderstood my question

Comment: After I inspect usage of the secret chat, I can only speculate it is build on top of the existing message exchange. The key exchange is just an additional key or index so FB can remove those message from the server. Honestly, with secret chat or not, I will avoid FB mobile apps for all cost due to various bug and design flaw. 
http://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/10/05/how-to-enable-and-use-secret-conversations-in-facebook-messenger/

Comment: This looks more like a vendor support question. Or one that requires more testing